# Copy-Item does not copy item when actioned by filesystemwatcher

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher, copy-item

I'm trying to create a watch folder on a network share that simply copies files (300mb-20gb) in size to a destination folder. The filesystemwatcher and subscription works great with small files (i.e. 1-3kb). However, larger files do not copy. I do see a copy is triggered in the verbose stream, but no file is copied to the destination folder.

```bsh
$Folder = "\\10.11.233.91\vol_tx01\delivered_media"
$Filter = "*.mxf"
$destination = "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\support\Testy"
$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Folder, $Filter -Property @{
  NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'Filename, LastAccess'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
  $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
  $name = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
  $ChangeType = $event.SourceEventargs.ChangeType
  $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
  Write-Host "The file '$name' was $ChangeType at $Timestamp"
  Copy-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Recurse -Verbose
}
```

Comment: `-Destination $destination` -> `-Destination $using:destination`?

Comment: What would that do Ansgar?

Comment: [`about_Scopes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: Thanks, doesn't fix the issue though

Comment: The "OnCreated" watcher alerts when the file is created, not completely written to. So this behavior is expected for large files as the writer might still be writing to the file under an exclusive lock - due to which your watcher won't be able to read it. You should additionally spin over trying to obtain exclusive lock on the file to be sure it's been completely written to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy-Item does not work with FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583244/copy-item-does-not-work-with-filesystemwatcher)

Comment: Not a ***possible*** duplicate, it is a duplicate question from the same user on the same subject -- please remove 1.