# Copy-Item does not work with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to create a watch folder on a network share that simply copies files (300mb-20gb) in size to a destination folder. The `FileSystemWatcher` and subscription works great with small files (i.e. 1-3kb). However, larger files do not copy. I do see a copy is triggered in the verbose stream, but no file is copied to the destination folder.

```
 $Folder = "\\10.11.233.91\vol_tx01\delivered_media"
 $Filter = "*.mxf"
 $destination = "C:\Users\Leeds TX 11\Desktop\support\Testy"
 $Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Folder, $Filter -Property @{
     NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'Filename, LastAccess'
 }

 $onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier `
 FileCreated -Action {
     $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
     $name = $event.SourceEventArgs.Name
     $ChangeType = $event.SourceEventargs.ChangeType
     $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
     Write-Host "The file '$name' was $ChangeType at $Timestamp"
     Copy-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Recurse -Verbose
 }
```

Comment: You're triggerring on the last time a file's accessed, rather than the last time it's written to.  Since copy-item will access the file, I'm guessing that causes it to trip.  Use `LastWrite` in your `NotifyFilter`..

Comment: Thanks John, I tried LastWrite as a NotifyFilter. It still won't copy any file over 2-3kb.

Comment: Another thought; do you only see this issue when triggering Copy-Item from the above script; or do you see the same issues when using Copy-Item from the same source to destination?  Is the only difference between those which work & those which don't their file size?  Sorry for so many questions; sadly I've not had a chance to test your code for myself yet / don't really know enough about the FSW to spot any issues without testing.

Answer (score 3):

Combination of issue were at hand. Firstly thank you JohnLBevan for pointing out LastWrite should be the notifyfilter to use. Also found that in this case copy-item does not wait for the file transfer in the source directory to close. I fixed this by putting in a while loop waiting for the file to be locked:

```
 ##################### DANGER BOX ####################################

    $Folder = "C:\Users\Leeds TX 12\Desktop\Source" #Source dir
    $Filter = "*.mxf" # MXF Filter
    $destination = "C:\Users\Leeds TX 12\Desktop\Destination" # Destination dir



################### Watch for file system events###########################

$Watcher = New-Object IO.FilesystemWatcher $Folder, $Filter -Property @{
NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'LastWrite, Filename'
}

################### Register filesystemwatcher & subscribe to notifyfilters ################# 

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier filecreated -Action {
$path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$ChangeType = $Event.SourceEventargs.ChangeType
$Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
write-host "The file '$name' was $ChangeType at $Timestamp" # Debug

################# Wait for file lock collapse #########################################

while($True)
{
Try {
      [IO.File]::OpenWrite($path).Close()
      Break
      }
   Catch { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}
   }

#################### Copy item #############################

Copy-item $path -Destination $Destination -force -Recurse -Verbose}
```

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution.  Looks like these guys reached the same conclusion / it's a common problem: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/avoiding-file-concurrency-using-system-io-filesystemwatcher/.  As such I've submitted an issue (suggestion) to the Dot Net GitHub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/437